# Using DictWriter to write a subset of a dictionary's keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I wrote a function that serializes a list of dictionaries as a CSV file using the `csv` module, with code like this:

```
data = csv.DictWriter(out_f, fieldnames)
data.writerows(dictrows)
```

However, I sometimes want to write out to a file only a subset of each dictionary's keys. If I pass as `fieldnames` a subset of the keys that each dictionary has, I get the error:

```
"dict contains fields not in fieldnames"
```

How can I make it so that DictRows will write just a subset of the fields I specify to CSV, ignoring those fields that are in the dictionary but not in fieldnames?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simplest and most direct approach is to pass `extrasaction='ignore'` when you initialize your `DictWriter` instance, as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter):

> If the dictionary passed to the
>   `writerow()` method contains a key not
>   found in fieldnames, the optional
>   extrasaction parameter indicates what
>   action to take. If it is set to
>   `'raise'` a `ValueError` is raised. If it
>   is set to `'ignore'`, extra values in
>   the dictionary are ignored.

It also works on `writerows`, which, internally, just calls `writerow` repeatedly.

Comment: The option restval for not found dictionary key is particulary useful together with extrasaction='ignore'.

Comment: As a reminder, a key subset looks like `['lat', 'lng']`.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to your code:

Forget Dictwriter, use ordinary writer.

Then loop over your list of dicts:

```
for d in dictrows:
    ordinary_writer.writerow([d[fieldname] for fieldname in fieldnames])
```

Use `d.get(fieldname, "")` instead of `d[fieldname]` if you don't want an exception if there is no entry in `d` for a `fieldname`.

Note to anonymous downvoters: This is doing what Alex's solution is doing under the hood (see Lib/csv.py) and doing it a bit better ... csv.py calls a function to get each row in a list, and the guts of that function is

```
return [rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames]
```

Comment: -1; no reason to do this when `DictWriter` provides a convenient parameter to solve the problem automatically, as described in Alex's answer.